# How can I use parallel execution on a single step of a Java Stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I am performing a single expensive operation in my stream manipulation which I would like to multithread, but remaining operations should be single threaded.  For example:

```
package test;

import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class TestStreams {
    private static Set<String> expensiveThreads = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();
    private static Set<String> cheapThreads = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IntStream.range(1, 1000).parallel().map(i -> myExpensiveMap(i))
                .unparallel()  //does not compile
                .forEach(i -> myCheapOperation(i));
        System.out.println("Expensive Threads:" + expensiveThreads);
        System.out.println("Cheap Threads:    " + cheapThreads);
    }

    private static void myCheapOperation(int i) {
        cheapThreads.add(Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }

    private static int myExpensiveMap(int i) {
        expensiveThreads.add(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return i;
    }
}
```

The current output is:

```
Expensive Threads:[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, main, ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3]
Cheap Threads:    [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, main, ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3]
```

But the output I would like is:

```
Expensive Threads:[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, main, ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3]
Cheap Threads:    [main]
```

I have tried wrapping the original stream using StreamSupport(Spliterator, false), but this limits the original stream to single thread processing.  For example:

```
StreamSupport.stream(
                IntStream.range(1, 1000).parallel().map(i -> myExpensiveMap(i))
                        .spliterator(), false)
                .forEach(i -> myCheapOperation(i));

Expensive Threads:[main]
Cheap Threads:    [main]
```

Or using parallel = true, for example:

```
StreamSupport.stream(
                IntStream.range(1, 1000).parallel().map(i -> myExpensiveMap(i))
                        .spliterator(), true)
                .forEach(i -> myCheapOperation(i));

Expensive Threads:[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, main, ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3]
Cheap Threads:    [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, main, ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3]
```

How can I unparallel this Stream?

Comment: Streams don’t work that way. And they don’t need to. If `myCheapOperation` is a cheap operation, there should be no problem executing it in parallel anyway.

Comment: This really affects encapsulation negatively.  I would like to be able to return a Stream from my library, however I cannot prevent the end programmer from consuming it in an unsupported way.  For example, I have to consider thread safety just in case the end programmer happens to use `.parallel()`, and I have to consider order in case they do or do not use forEachOrdered.  Is there no way to wrap a stream so that the chained instructions only affect it downstream?

Comment: You don’t have to consider that at all. The function you pass to `map` should *always* be non-interfering and stateless and if it fulfills that contract, you don’t have to care about thread safety. And you never have to care about the order. Either, your stream has a defined encounter order or it hasn’t. If it has, the Stream will take care.

Answer (score 1):

The opposite of `.parallel` is [`.sequential`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/BaseStream.html#sequential--):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    IntStream.range(1, 1000).parallel().map(i -> myExpensiveMap(i))
            .sequential()
            .forEach(i -> myCheapOperation(i));
    System.out.println("Expensive Threads:" + expensiveThreads);
    System.out.println("Cheap Threads:    " + cheapThreads);
}
```

Comment: I was not aware of sequential, however, the sequential() call seems to override the parallel() call.

`Expensive Threads:[main]`
`Cheap Threads:    [main]`

Comment: There may be no alternative but to dump it into a collection after the first operation, then stream that for the second operation.

Comment: @Louis Wasserman: there is. The alternative is to just let the second operation run in parallel. Being cheap doesn’t preclude parallel execution.